# Autocomplete a function argument VALUE

Tags: python-3.x

It's possible to autocomplete the arguments of a function. For example:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)
```

If you type `foo(` and press tab, you will get a list of the possible arguments (a, b, c) to pass. What I'm wondering is if you can autocomplete the values as well, for instance typing `foo(a=` and pressing tab would display the "allowed values list" predefined somewhere else (where? how?).

I know it's possible to check for specific values at the start of the function and raise an error if the parameter passed is not in the allowed values list, like that:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    if a not in (1, 2, 3):
        raise Exception("/!\\ Parameter 'a' has an unsupported value.")
    print(a, b, c)
```

What I would love to have is a way for the user to write clean code directly without having to read the API's documentation. To be honest I don't expect it's possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any IDE that supports [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) already does this.

Comment: This is a feature of whatever IDE you're using, not Python.  You should tag the appropriate IDE.

Comment: @BradSolomon Yes specific values.

Comment: @blhsing I know about type hints, I was hoping for a "value hint" of some sort.